# A problem with Castle.Core.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

the thing is I have an issue with Castle.Core.dll. I've installed RC3 from their website, so I have 1.0.3.0 version of DLL.
I`m studying MVC framework using Steve Sanderson's book (which is great, btw) and running samples.
Project compiled successfully, all was running, but suprisingly today I've got this runtime exception:

```
Method not found: 'Void Castle.Core.Configuration.ConfigurationCollection.AddRange(Castle.Core.Configuration.ConfigurationCollection)'
```

It's strange because before today project was OK, all worked well. I checked on RedGate's Reflector - this method **is present** in the DLL.
So, any ideas what I've done wrong? I restarted VS, deleted reference and added it again - in vain:(. Googling does nothing for me - many people have similar troubles, but not exactly.
**EDIT:**
And, by the way, I've tried Steve's code downloaded from apress.com. It didn`t work - the reason is the same.

Comment: Updated the answer - yes Windsor 2.0 is the version to go with

Comment: I`ve got a little trouble - how to reference them now? I`ve installed assemblies in GAC, rebooted PC. But from the "Browse" tab I can`t add them to my project - they don`t show up in reference node in VS:(

Comment: Remove them from GAC altogether. Download .zip file with Windsor 2.0, extract it to some folder on your disk. In your solution remove old references to Castle, then click "Add Reference"->Browse, navigate to the folder you extracted the zip to, and add references to the 4 Castle assemblies.

Comment: it worked, thanks! now I have problems with web.config http module section:(

Comment: why don't you ask the question on the Castle users group... it fits better for the q-a-q-a... style of conversation. Ensure you have the right full name of the assembly in the web config (you can peek at it in Reflector, and copy paste from there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATE - pulling what's in comments to the body of the answer]

- Ensure you have no old (RC) version installed in your GAC, if you do - uninstall it.
- Download binary package of Windsor 2.0 (or newer if available) and unzip it to a folder on your hard drive
- Remove old references in your project. Add references to the files you extracted in the above step
- Ensure you updated version number in your app.config (can be copied from Reflector)